# Actualizar input number - Jquery

Tags: jquery

Buenas tardes quiero que cuando le doy a mis botones de más y menos cantidad ejecute la misma función que los botones de más y menos de un input number normal. Necesito obtener la unidades que se van eligiendo en el momento.

Si os dais cuenta, al lado de adultos si le das a los botones normal del input si que cambia, pero con los otros no.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#prueba').on('input', function() {
        $('#mirror').text($('#prueba').val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
    <td class="font14"><strong>Adultos <span id="mirror"></span></strong></td>
    <td class="td_flex">
        <div class="number-input posicion_cantidad_carrito">
            <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" ></button>
            <input class="qtHuespedes backCantidad" min="0" name="qtHuespedes" value="0" type="number" id="prueba">
            <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus"></button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo tu código actualizado

Tu problema es que no tienes un evento que lea ese cambio, coloque una clase a los botones para leer ese cambio

```js
    $('#prueba').on('input', function() {
        $('#mirror').text($('#prueba').val());
    });
    $(".cantidad").click(function()
    {
        $('#mirror').text($('#prueba').val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
    <td class="font14"><strong>Adultos <span id="mirror"></span></strong></td>
    <td class="td_flex">
        <div class="number-input posicion_cantidad_carrito">
            <button class="cantidad" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" ></button>
            <input class="qtHuespedes backCantidad" min="0" name="qtHuespedes" value="0" type="number" id="prueba">
            <button class="cantidad" class="cambiocantidad" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus"></button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, dos preguntas ¿Por que ponemos dos veces `$('#mirror').text($('#prueba').val());` ? y ¿Podria guardar ese valor en una variable y actualizarla, según va incrementando o descendiendo? Gracias!

Comment: Si, podrías colocar en una variable, la coloque así para que justo entiendas que fue lo que hice y se entienda

Comment: Nada, ya lo tengo muchas gracias por la ayuda ;)